# Сортировка QSortFilterProxyModel через QTableView, пустая строка всегда внизу

Tags: c++, qt

Я пытаюсь сделать редактируемую таблицу с добавлением строк с помощью редактирования последней строки. Я хотел бы сортировать такую таблицу так, чтобы последняя строка всегда оставалась внизу. Для этого, я создал подкласс `QSortFilterProxyModel` и реализовал в нём функцию `lessThan`, как описано в [ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29363360/8125936):

```
bool CatalogueSortFilterProxy::lessThan(const QModelIndex &left, const QModelIndex &right) const
{
    auto leftData = sourceModel()->data(left, Qt::DisplayRole).toString(),
            rightData = sourceModel()->data(right, Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
    qDebug() << (sortRole() ? "Descending sort" : "Ascending sort");
    if (leftData == "+")
        return sortRole() == Qt::AscendingOrder;
    else if (rightData == "+")
        return sortRole() == Qt::DescendingOrder;
    else return leftData < rightData;
}
```

Прокси-модель назначена `QTableView`, в котором включен `sortingEnabled`. При попытке отсортировать модель через вид я обнаружил, что `sortRole` в прокси-модели всегда `Qt::AscendingOrder`, вне зависимости от параметров сортировки. Из-за этого строка для добавления будет первой или последней в зависимости от направления сортировки выбранного пользователем.

Comment: Попробуйте поменять `sortRole()` на `sortOrder()`.

Answer (score -1):

как указал alexis031182, нужно было

> поменять `sortRole()` на `sortOrder()`

Comment: Чужие ответы стоит помечать флажком "Общий"